# Filter a list based on Navigation Bar categories

Tags: java, android, search, navigation-drawer

This is my `filter()` method which is in my `RecyclerAdapter.class`:

```
//Do search..
    public void filter(final String text) {
        // dispatch search to a different thread
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // clear the filteredList
            filteredList.clear();

            //if there is no search value load the whole list
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
                filteredList.addAll(chordsList);
            } else {
                //iterate through the original list and add to the filteredList
                for (Chord chord : chordsList) {
                    if (chord.getName().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())) {
                        filteredList.add(chord);
                    }
                }
            }

            //set on UI thread
            ((Activity) mContext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

        }
    }).start();
}
```

It is based on two Lists the `chordsList`, which contains the whole list, and the filteredList, which, as the name suggests, contains only those elements that contain the `text` String.

It is called in my `MainActivity` like this:

```
adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this, chords);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
    filteredList = adapter.getFilteredList();
```

and then in the `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` method:

```
final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    setupSearch();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            adapter.filter(newText);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Now what I need to do is in the `onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)` method, when I tap on a specific category, I need the list to be filtered based on the category associated String.

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    // TODO: da rivedere
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_c) {
    // String text = "c"
    // filteredList = all items containing c
    // inflate the recyclerView with the new filteredList
    }
    ...
```

It would be great if you'd help me out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working fine. Just `recyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged();` missing in `else` part of `filter` method. Write something like this:

```java
//if there is no search value load the whole list
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
    filteredList.addAll(chordsList);
} else {
    //iterate through the original list and add to the filteredList
    for (Chord chord : chordsList) {
        if(chord.getName().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase()))  {
            filteredList.add(chord);
        }
    }
}

recyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

it will work for sure. let me know if any problem :)

thanks